# Make entire button clickable without js using a bootstrap 5 button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

When including an a tag inside a button tag, you have to click on the actual text in order for the page to redirect. Is there anyway to make it so that no matter where you click on the button, it'll redirect you? Here's the button code, uses Bootstrap 5.

```
<button class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary" type="button">Placeholder Text</button>
```

`.btn-rounded` is just `border-radius: .5rem;`

I could just place an a tag outside the button tags, though I'm pretty sure that's not valid based on HTML5 specifications, so I'm probably not going to do that.
I could also just write functions for it like:

```
function goTO() {
  window.location.href = "https://google.com"
}
```

and just add a onclick thing for the button and tell it to run said function when I click the button, though that would be very redundant and inefficient if I have many buttons.

So, is there anyway to be able to click on a corner of a button but have it act as if I clicked on the text inside the button (which is basically the a tag that's inside the button) and then have the page redirect me to that new page without writing functions for each button?

Comment: why don't you use the `a` tag for that, e.g. `<a href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary" type="button">Placeholder Text</a>` - all bootstrap version only focus on the class `btn btn-rounded btn-primary` - we can modify it as we want.

Comment: @JoeKdw I did try that after realizing that's something I could do, though I would have to either completely change how the button looks because of the text location (which I'd rather not because I like how it looks right now) or figure out how to center "Placeholder Text" in the middle of the "button"

Comment: Our friend's answer is good to show you how to center the "placeholder text". If you find it not working on your project, i think the problem is the container div (or such) as a wrapper of the button. You can provide more to see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question ... why do you need an "a tag inside a button tag"?  Just use the button without the "a" tag.

HTML `<button>` tags always behave the same - the entire button is "clickable".

Your code would look like this:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary" onclick="goTO()">Placeholder Text</button>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/wts8g34v/).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply height(100%) and width(100%) to `a` tag by changing it's display type(block, inline-block, flex, etc) and remove unnecessary padding for button tag thus both `button` and it's nested `a` tag will have same height and width.

```css
button {
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

button a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary" type="button">
  <a href="https://google.com" >Placeholder Text</a>
</button>
```